# How to change the Index of an objects in Flash with ActionScript 3?

Tags: arrays, flash, object, actionscript, indexing

I need  to change the index of and object generated by a class. 
I know this code myObject.parent.setChildIndex( myObject, newZIndex);
but it only works on movieclips found on the stage.

when i try to use it on a class so every ball that falls gets behind the Bag that catches those balls. No matter what index I give to the Bag which is a movieclip, the balls always get in front of the bag, I need to change the index of the balls (from a class located in an array), to an index lower than the bag's index.

appreciate any help, ty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your approach in solving this issue.

Create a `Sprite` layer for your bag and a `Sprite` layer for your balls.

Add the balls layer first, then the bag layer.

If you do that, it'll be impossible for the bag to appear behind a ball.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I didn't learn sprite yet so I have no Idea how to use it. I need an example of the code or something.

Comment: Probably best for you to take a step back and learn about the display list. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html